# Graphics Card DVI-I Connector to LCD Monitor's DVI-D

Tags: sync, lcd, dvi

Planning to replace an older ATI Radeon 7500 w/ an AGP card w/ 1gb memory.  When odd-colored pixels started showing random patterns, I decided to try the DVI-I connector (on the video card) to see if it would fix the prob.  After much reading about DVI cable connections, purchased a good quality DVI-D to DVI-D male/male cable.  No luck when connecting to the DVI-D receptacle on my Princeton flat-panel monitor.  One article I read talked about disabling pnp on the computer's BIOS, but my Sony Vaio PCV-RX580 doesn't have that on its BIOS.  Since I'm not attempting to connect dual monitors, this should be relatively simple.  Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are the odd pixels always at the same place and color? Then you rather have a lcd screen pixel problem. Which usually can not be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

DVI-I-to-DVI-D should ‘just work’. Some monitors will switch inputs automatically, others will have to be told to change source.

I don't think you'll avoid the corruption by switching to DVI though. Bad pixel patterns are generally a sign of hardware messed up at the digital end (typically in the memory) rather than in the d2a converter stage.